# Python-Regex-Distinguish and use repeated pattern in a string

Tags: python, html, regex, string

**Edit:** so I came to realize, with the kind help from answers below, that parsing html with regex is generally a bad idea. For what it's worth, if someone else comes across my post someday with the same question, here's a link to two similar questions on this topic, with a far greater deal of debate and explanation that you might find useful: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) and this one: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

**Specs:** Python 3.3.1

**What I was trying to do:** I was writing a web page extractor to grab the weather data from a website, which for my project has 3 meaningful sections: temperature "Right Now", "Earlier Today" and "Tonight". I intend to grab these 3 numbers only and leave out all other text. In the code below I used the presence of specific html elements preceding the temperature number as pattern to help me grab the number itself.

All the data I need is in this block of html code excerpt: (namely `89`,`96` and `80`)

```
<div class="wx-timepart-title">
Earlier Today
</div>
<div class="wx-timepart-title">Tonight</div>
<div class="wx-data-part wx-first">
<img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20120328.084208/img/wxicon/120/29.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Partly Cloudy" class="wx-weather-icon">
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20120328.084208/img/wxicon/120/30.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Partly Cloudy" class="wx-weather-icon">
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20120328.084208/img/wxicon/120/29.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Partly Cloudy" class="wx-weather-icon">
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part wx-first">
<div class="wx-temperature"><span itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit">89</span><span class="wx-degrees">&deg;<span class="wx-unit">F</span></span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">FEELS LIKE
<span itemprop="feels-like-temperature-fahrenheit">94</span>&deg;</div>
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<div class="wx-temperature">96<span class="wx-degrees">&deg;</span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">HIGH AT 4:45 PM</div>
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<div class="wx-temperature">80<span class="wx-degrees">&deg;</span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">LOW</div>
</div>
```

**The solution I came up with:**

```
import urllib.request
import re

# open the webpage and read the html code into a string; 
base = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.weather.com/weather/today/Washington+DC+USDC0001:1:US')
f = base.readlines()
f = str(f)


# temperature "Right Now" 
match1 = re.search(r'<div class="wx-temperature"><span itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit">\w\w',f)

if match1:
    result1 = match1.group()
    right_now = result1[68:]
    print(right_now)


# temperature "Earlier Today"
match2 = re.search(r'<div class="wx-temperature">\w\w',f)

if match2:
    result2 = match2.group()
    ealier_today = result2[28:]
    print(ealier_today)


# temperature "Tonight"
match3 = re.search(r'<div class="wx-temperature">\w\w',f)

if match3:
    result3 = match3.group()
    tonight = result3[28:]
    print(tonight)
```

The three print statements are just for testing if data was grabbed correctly.

**My question:** problem occurred when it came to the third regex(`match3`), displaying the temperature for `match2`. I figure it's because it uses the same regex pattern as the second? So I guess my question is that how do you search for multiple results with the same regex pattern. Or is it that you can only grab the first occurrence of a pattern? I'm quite new to Python and it's my first few days into regular expression. I appreciate it if you could share some general pointers about my solution, or about my general line of thinking towards this project. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use regex to parse html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand your question, but you are merely looking for [findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)?

```
match3 = re.findall(r'<div class="wx-temperature">\w\w',f)
```

Also, you might find it easier to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or something along those lines. Parsing html with regexes is hellish. Further, you might as well not reinvent the wheel, since python has hundreds of well-built modules that have already done a lot of work for you. You could do the following after installing bs4:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''<div class="wx-timepart-title">
Earlier Today
</div>
<div class="wx-timepart-title">Tonight</div>
<div class="wx-data-part wx-first">
<img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20120328.084208/img/wxicon/120/29.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Partly Cloudy" class="wx-weather-icon">
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20120328.084208/img/wxicon/120/30.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Partly Cloudy" class="wx-weather-icon">
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20120328.084208/img/wxicon/120/29.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Partly Cloudy" class="wx-weather-icon">
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part wx-first">
<div class="wx-temperature"><span itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit">89</span><span class="wx-degrees">&deg;<span class="wx-unit">F</span></span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">FEELS LIKE
<span itemprop="feels-like-temperature-fahrenheit">94</span>&deg;</div>
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<div class="wx-temperature">96<span class="wx-degrees">&deg;</span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">HIGH AT 4:45 PM</div>
</div>
<div class="wx-data-part">
<div class="wx-temperature">80<span class="wx-degrees">&deg;</span></div>
<div class="wx-temperature-label">LOW</div>
</div>  '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for temp in soup.find_all(class_="wx-temperature"):
    print(temp.text)       # or add these to a list or make a list comprehension


89°F
96°
80°
```

If you merely want the digits (and possibly a negative), you can do this:

```
>>> import re
>>> for temp in soup.find_all(class_="wx-temperature"):
    print(re.match(r'-?\d+', temp.text).group())


89
96
80
```

This approach would give you some flexibility in case the weather ever drops to one digit or goes up to three digits. I added the `-?`, which means 0 or 1 occurrences of the character `-`, in case you run across negative temps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! didn't realize this conventional wisdom about it being a bad idea to parse html with regex. and great answer using BeautifulSoup. Thanks!

Comment: You bet. I hope you find BeautifulSoup as helpful as I have.